# VBA formula equivalent in Google Sheets. ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value * 3

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for Google Sheets equivalent of VBA ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value * 3

It should multiply active cell by a numer (3) and write it down in the same cell.

I don't know JavaScript at all...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.range.getCell(1,1).setValue(e.value * 3);
}
```

It will multiply by 3 a value of every edited cell. Just as an example.

But I don't know how exactly would you want to use it? Implementation heavily depends on it. It's likely there should be some conditions to limit the function by some columns, etc.

Comment: I just want to assign this to a button with no extra conditions, just for multiply active cell.

Comment: Probably @Cooper's implementation will do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function times3() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell().setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell().getValue() * 3);
}
```